# How to automate Python Script in Cron Job without .py file extension

Tags: python-3.x, cron

I want to run the command `webscreenshot` automatically (project found at https://pypi.org/project/webscreenshot/#description).

This command should run via `cron` task or `systemd` automatically, every 15 minutes.

Running a `linux` server with `python3.6`, I've tried to incorporate this as a `cron` task but it is failing. Should I create my own `python` script to automate this?

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/user/.local/bin/webscreenshot -i /home/user/projects/webscreenshot/data.txt -o /home/user/projects/webscreenshot/screenshots > /home/user/projects/log.txt 2>&1
```

I expect this to run the `python` script `webscreenshot` but this is not the case, screenshots are not produced.

Comment: Just out of interest, why have you removed the `.py` extension - it's generally considered good practice to leave it in for clarity and portability?

Comment: What does the cron log say?

Answer (score 0):

@Ari - the .py extension is left out by the default installation.

I was able to get this to work by adding

`xvfb-run` to the begging, to read:

`xvfb-run /dir/to/webscreenshot -i file.txt -o /output/dir/screenshots`